# How can you find the maximum nth integer in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function, module

From a random list I created through a function, how can I create a function that checks the list for an nth maximum which is an input from the user? I have my first function that creates the list and everything completed. But I can't find a way to write a program that finds the nth maximum, I asked this question before but it is always mistaken as find the first three maximums or create a function just to find the max or second max, etc. But it can be any maximum in the list. I tried the method of sorting it in a list and pulling out the nth max from there but it didn't go through...

For Example:

If the list has the values 1 3 7 2 15 20 5 18 11 and the user wanted the:

1st Maximum (n = 1)  -> It would return 20 (the highest number)

2nd Maximum (n = 2) -> It would return 18 (the second highest number)

3rd Maximum (n = 3) -> It would return 15 (the third highest number)

Comment: What should the output be in the case of duplicates?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. If there's duplicates, it will still go through to the nth maximum

Comment: Sort the list, and then take the Nth element from the end.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: i'm not sure how to write a function for it